# Require() and include() not working in Eclipse for code assist and autocomplete

Tags: php, eclipse, ide

I just started using Eclipse PHP.

I finally figured out how to turn on auto complete code assist.

My problem is that when I use require or include, those variables in those files aren't showing up.

Example,

code1.php

```
<? $test = 'hi'; ?>
```

code2.php

```
<? require('code1.php'); ?>
```

When I am editing code2.php, $test variable doesn't show up in auto complete (aka code assist)

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse 3.6 with PDT 2.2.1, I was able to **solve this issue** by going to:

**Window->Preferences->PHP->Editor->CodeAssist**

and then enabling **"Show variables from other files"**, and clicking Apply.

This was the only way I could get the autocompletion to work for non-class-type variables defined in external files.

Answer (score 0):

The code completion is cached. Try to refresh the cache. Also make sure that both files are added to your current project.

Answer (score 0):

To tell eclipse where the included files are, add them under Right Click on your Project and select Properties then add the path to your classes.